# Fecha en Firebase

Tags: date, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy obteniendo la fecha asi => `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();`

y en la Base de datos me sale así => `1 de junio de 2019, 17:40:06 UTC-3`

Pero cuando le hago console me tira esto en nanosegundos y segundos, alguien podria  decirme como convertir eso en fecha?

Codigo=>

```
querySnapshot.forEach( (doc)=>{
            $('.NotifyMsm').append(`
            <div class="dropdown-item Finish PointerNotify" onclick="OpenSend(${doc.data().MID}, '${doc.data().nameDOC}')">
              <p><i class="far fa-user"></i> <small>${doc.data().NOMBRE}</small> </p>
              <p>
              <small><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> ${doc.data().contenidoMsm}</small></p>
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i>${console.log(doc.data().Fecha['seconds'])}
            </div>`)
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

quizás ya es un poco tarde para responder a esta pregunta, pero por las dudas alguien tiene la misma duda, para solucionar este problema podrían multiplicar los segundos por 1000, todo dentro del objeto Date().

Ejemplo: {`${new Date(created_at.seconds * 1000)}`}